# Bootstrap 3 responsive height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to show some panels on a page, but I would like the panel body to have a height of 100% on a page, but my CSS knowledge apparently isn't up to scratch.

If I specify a height (like 100px), then it's gets height, but it isn't responsive.

Does anybody know how I could do this?

I have a JSFiddle of my set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/skeniver/47CZ6/5/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Heading
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This doesn't overwrite your Bootstrap base CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/YzHu4/

HTML

```
<div class="container m100">
    <div class="panel panel-default m100">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Heading
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body m100">            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.m100 {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS set the height to 100% rather than 100px

.panel-body {height:100%;}

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, but that doesn't work because the container doesn't use the full page either.

I also added 100% heights to the html, body and container but nothing changes the height of the panel...

Answer (score 0):

Any panel containers also need to be 100% height -- body,html and .container:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

.container,.panel {
    height:100%;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/111090